# where can I see the echo result when use git hooks?

Tags: git, deployment, echo, hook

I just want to know whether the post-receive git hook scripts have been executed,
so I added an echo command to the bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "just test"
```

When I run `git push` on local repo, nothing happened on the remote server.
Where can I see the echoed result string from remote server or somewhere else?
I have run `chmod +x post-receive` and the owner of `post-receive` is `git:git`

Comment: Of course you modified the script on the _remote_ repository, right? And the push you tried to run succeeded, and you did have modifications to push?

Comment: To be sure you're doing the right things I advise you to make a quick test between two local temporary repositories

Comment: Check the server logs

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I met it now, though it worked before.